# how to execute the running time of a program written in c++?

Tags: c++, performance, ctime, time.h

I have code that generates random numbers from 1-100 and sorts them using the merge sort which I already have in a separate function. Everything works but when I implement clock(); to try and get the running time, I always get zero. I have even tried with larger numbers like 10000 but still, the time passed always gives me zero. here is my code

```
int main() {
clock_t startTime;
clock_t endTime;
clock_t timePassed;

int array[100];
srand(time(NULL));
int n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
startTime = clock();
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
        array[j] = rand() % 100+1;
        std::cout << array[j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    MergeSort(array, n);

    std::cout << "After Merge Sort :" << std::endl;
    PrintArray(array, n);

    endTime = clock();
    timePassed = ((endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout << "\n" << timePassed;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it giving you 0 or 0.00? could it be that it's rounding? Try `cout.precision(9999);`

Comment: try `float(timePassed)`

Comment: the `std::chrono` faculties of the standard library will give you better and more accurate results.

Comment: A bit of terminology: you don't *implement* `clock`, you just are using it. `clock` is *implemented* inside your C++ or C standard library (on Linux, using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) ...)

Comment: May be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433440/how-to-check-time-performances-in-a-c-program-on-zedboard/44433887#44433887

Comment: `clock_t` is an integer type, so `timePassed` will always be set to zero if your program takes less than 1 second to run.  If you want finer granularity than one second, you should use floating point math rather than integer math when dividing by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` (and store the result in a `float` variable)

Comment: thank you I changed timepassed to float type and I am receiving a very low number when I run the program with an array size of 100. I get 0.013 for the time passed. This seems more reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
double timePassed = (endTime - startTime) / static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Plan B for higher accuracy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// ...

auto start_time{ std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() };

// ... code you want to time

auto end_time{ std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() };

std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << ":";
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << ":";

// ...
```

Comment: changing my timepassed type to double and float seems to have given me a number that is not zero. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on a Unix system and want to measure the execution time from an application, you can also use the 'time' command like:

**time myapplication**

see
[time (Unix) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix))