# How to calculate time in milliseconds of functions of bubble sort, insertion sort and selection sort in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

which functions should use to calculate the time of a function
Is there any built-in function for this purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433440/how-to-check-time-performances-in-a-c-program-on-zedboard

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
auto a = chrono::steady_clock::now();

//write your code here

auto b = chrono::steady_clock::now();
double time = chrono::duration <double, milli> (b - a).count();
cout << endl << "Time ---> " << time;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built in specifically for calculating the time taken by a function.

There are functions built in to retrieve the current time. See [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now) for more details about that.

To time a function, you'd (at least normally) retrieve the current time just after entering the function, and again just before exiting.

You can then subtract the two, and use [`std::duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) to convert that to a duration in terms of period that's convenient (milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds, as the case may be).

Putting those together, you could (for example) get something like this:

```cpp
template <class T, class U, template<class, class> class F, typename ...Args>
auto timer(F<T,U> f, std::string const &label, Args && ...args) {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto holder = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << label << " time: " << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count() << "\n";

    return holder;
}
```

This lets you pass some arbitrary function (and arguments to be passed to that function) and prints out the time the function took to execute. At the moment it's doing microseconds, but changing that to milliseconds should be trivial.

At the end, this returns whatever value the called function produced, so if you had something like:

```
x = f(a, b, c);
```

You could replace that with:

```
x = timer(f, a, b, c);
```

...to get the time consumed by `f` printed out.

Comment: Isn't `std::steady_clock` usually recommended for timing things? The `std::high_resolution_clock` is allowed to be the same as the `std::system_clock` which is subject to time alterations external to the process.

Comment: Any function in time.h library that we can use for this purpose?

Comment: std::high_resolution_clock on Linux is just a wrapper around clock_gettime() which is a kernel call, although it is usually a VDSO and resolved in userspace. Still, the clock can warp back in time if the NTP/PTP offset is too large. steady_clock is guaranteed not to jump or warp in time.

Comment: @Galik: I'm not sure about "usually recommended", but it sounds like a poor tradeoff to me. For timing a function, your top priority is resolution. Yes, in most places there are two times a year that your function might record a time around 1 hour or -1 hours, but if you care about milliseconds, an hour such a massive outlier that filtering it out is utterly trivial.

Comment: @AsadullahShaukat: Not reliably, no. `clock()` is probably the closest. It's supposed to give CPU time, but some implementations give wall time instead, and resolution is often pretty coarse (frequently on the order of tens to hundreds of milliseconds). `time()` is supposed to give wall time, and it usually has a resolution of one second.

Comment: Don't forget that many/most computers these days are connected to a time-server and they get small corrections to the system time continually to stay synchronized.

Comment: @AsadullahShaukat: if you can use non-portable code, chances are pretty good your OS provides something with finer resolution. Windows has `QueryPerformanceCounter`, with a resolution that can vary (you use `QueryPerformanceFrequency` to get the resolution). Linux (and most UNIXesque OSes) has a whole raft of slightly different functions, with different resolutions and conventions--`gettimeofday`, `clock_gettime`, `gethrtime`, `gethrvtime`, and so on.

Comment: @Galik: Not even close to continuously, and (at least decently written ones) typically wait for the system to be idle before applying a correction as well.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do not count time in seconds as it will be different on machines with different CPU frequencies. I typically use CPU cycles such that it will be roughly the same number if you run on a laptop or on an overclocked high-end server. Cycles also reflect and relate better to other machine characteristics as CPU cache latencies. This is what the Linux kernel uses internally

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
tsc
```

Every CPU architecture has some sort of internal timestamp counter. On x86_64 it is the TSC (time stamp counter) that can be read with the Intel intrinsic '__builtin_ia32_rdtsc()` as in

```
#include <cstdint>
static inline std::uint64_t now() {
    return __builtin_ia32_rdtsc();
}
```

Then on your code you can do something like this:

```
std::uint64_t t0 = now();
call_my_algo();
uint64_t t1 = now();
uint64_t ticks = t1>=t0 ? t1-t0 : (std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() - t0)+t1;
```

The last line is to take care of rollover but that should happen only once in 177 years so not really a concern. You can get away with just `t1-t0`.

The advantage of the rdtsc call against std::chrono is that you are not calling the glibc and the kernel, which is what chrono eventually does. The overhead is minimal so this method is perfect for micro-benchmarking.

There are a few things to be aware of. Each core contains its own timestamp counter so if they are unsynchronized then you might have a wrong reading if the process moves from one core to the other or the new timestamp might be lower than start such that the difference becomes negative - and therefore ticks will underflow. But those are rare nowadays, it's more common in old machines.

You can check if the TSC on your machine is to be trusted with

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep tsc | tr ' ' '\n' | grep tsc | sort | uniq
constant_tsc
nonstop_tsc
rdtscp
tsc
tsc_scale
```

constant_tsc - the timestamp counter frequency is constant

nonstop_tsc - the counter does not stop in C states

rdtscp - cpu has the rdtscp instruction (returns timestamp and core)

tsc - cpu has timestamp counter

tsc_scale - amd tsc scaling support

You should be careful that no matter if you use std::chrono, which will eventually call clock_gettime() on Linux, or if you use the TSC, the compiler might invert the order of your statements such that the code above can become

```
std::uint64_t t0 = now();
uint64_t t1 = now();
uint64_t ticks = t1>=t0?t1-t0 : (std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() - t0)+t1;
call_my_algo();
```

And therefore you will be measuring nothing. One way to avoid this is placing a optimization barrier like

```
#include <cstdint>
static inline std::uint64_t now() {
    asm volatile ( "" ::: "memory" );
    return __builtin_ia32_rdtsc();
}
```

There is also the matter of memory barriers that can be very involving.

Comment: Is your "start" actually your "t0"?

Comment: Yes! That was a typo, I'll fix it now.