# C++ memory profiler

Tags: c++, memory, profiler

I couldn't find any free c++ profiler with good interface for vs2005 running on 32bit winxp sp3. is there any free?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818673/memory-profiler-for-c

Answer (score 0):

You can download a 30 day evaluation of VTune from Intel: [software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/)

Comment: but can it really do memory profiling, instead of CPU profiling?

Comment: Yes, I haven't actually used it but apparently it works with the CPU performance registers so you should be able to profile cache misses, memory bandwidth, etc.