# Performance Profiling with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

How can I get Visual Studio to help me optimize my application, or tell me areas of slowness? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best Free C++ Profiler for windows (if there are)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As another suggestion, I have found the [AMD CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/codeanalyst/codeanalystwindows/Pages/default.aspx) a great companion. It integrates with VS2010 very well, and provides detailed breakdown of CPU time on a line-to-line basis. You can zoom in and out to see from a top-level to a function-level. Not to mention it even has in-line disassembly display if you need that extra bit of information!

Totally worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2013 Professional then you can use the Performance and Diagnostics hub: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/12/performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx . This profiler is well integrated in the IDE and I've found it really quick and easy for spotting code hotspots.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the super enterprise edition it's built in (but I haven't used it - and I think it's ability to profile unmanaged code is limited)

Otherwise see [What's the best free C++ profiler for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are)

Answer (score -3):

The Windows SysInternals website has a number of other useful utilities for network management, security, system information and more. Check it out. I’m sure you’ll find something of value.

Here is how it helped me:

Slow Visual Studio Performance … Solved!

I had an odd performance-related issue today. My Microsoft Visual Studio seemed to be taking far too long to perform even the simplest of operations. I Googled around and tried a few ideas that people had such as disabling add-ins or clearing Visual Studio’s recent projects list but those suggestions didn’t seem to solve the problem. I remembered that the Windows SysInternals website had a tool called Process Monitor that would sniff registry and file accesses by any running program. It seemed to me that Visual Studio was up to something and Process Monitor should help me figure out what it was. I downloaded the most recent version, and after fiddling around a bit with its display filters, ran it and to my horror, I saw that Visual Studio was so slow because it was accessing the more than 10,000 folders in C:\Users\krintoul\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache on most IDE operations. I’m not sure why there were that many folders and moreover, wasn’t sure what Visual Studio was doing with them, but after I zipped those folders up and moved them somewhere else, Visual Studio’s performance improved tremendously.