# Visual Studio 2010 or C/C++ performance monitors

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, performance

I was wondering if there were any tools that allow me to see roughly how long it takes to run through a function or program. Such as it would tell you that your typical merge sort alogrithim ran ~nlogn or took x time per n or to complete. Stuff like that.

It seems like Visual Studio Ultimate and Team has something that does stuff like that for you but I don't have that so looking for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give a couple of them a shot. I actually checked and found that I do have access to MSV2010 Ultimate so I'll try their tools as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a performance profiler
[What's the best free C++ profiler for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are)

Answer (score 1):

Particularly for ASP.Net I have used [DevPartner Performance Analysis](http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/DevPartner/doc/NSH823/HTML/DPPACE_KnownIssues.htm) set of tools, there you can run code and memory analysis, this integrates with Visual Studio 2008. Some well known algorithms are associated with their complexity order, for example:

```
Bubble, Insertion Selection --> O( n x n )
Quicksort, MergeSort --> O( nlog(n) )
Binsort, Radix --> O(n)
```

Also, Performance monitor refers to tools for checking the healt of performance counters.