# Optimizing a program (c)

Tags: c, optimization

i have my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r, line = 0, found = 0;
    float temp, t_tot = 0;
    char loc[32];


    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error opening the file\n\n'");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (argc == 3)
    {
        while ((r = fscanf(fp, "%f %s\n", &temp, loc)) != EOF)
        {
            line++;

            if (r == 2)
            {
                if(strcmp(argv[2], loc) == 0)
                {
                    t_tot += temp;
                    found++;
                }
            }
            else
                printf ("Error, line %d in wrong format!\n\n", line);
        }

        printf ("The average temperature in %s is: %.1f\n\n", argv[2], (t_tot/found));
    }

    fclose(fp)

    return 0;

}
```

The program needs to read all the line and find the city i wrote on argv[2]. Than it will tell me the average temperature on that city, notifying me if a line in the file is in a wrong format.

I'm wondering how can i "optimize" this code to be more efficient and writing the same things in a more "compact" way. I'm a student so all suggestions are accepted.

Comment: This would be more suitable at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It seems to me well structured yet.

Comment: It is a common practice to check `argc` at the top of your `main`, and not return to the check in the loop.

Comment: It is a common practice to use, for instance, `GNU getopt`, while we're at it :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Get a profiler** like GNU GProf or perhaps AMD CodeAnalyst.

See also [What's the best free C++ profiler for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are)

Then compile your program with highest optimisation and try to examine which parts tend to take much time.

Optimising without a profiler is generally to be avoided.

---

While we're at it, your program doesn't really do any calculations that would take lots of time, and its performance is likely to be bound by the I/O (my guess).

Another thing you could do, instead of optimising, is to **make it safe and correct**- for instance so that it wouldn't crash if a string from the input file is longer than 32 characters.

Answer (score 1):

you can also optimize the object code with compiler optimization option. For gcc just add `-O3` (or `-O1` or `-O2` , depending on the level of optimization) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing

```
if (r == 2)
{
    if(strcmp(argv[2], loc) == 0)
    {
        t_tot += temp;
        found++;
    }
} else {
    printf ("Error, line %d in wrong format!\n\n", line);
}
```

into this, to avoid the nested if block:

```
if (r == 2 && strcmp(argv[2], loc) == 0) {
    t_tot += temp;
    found++;
} else if (r != 2) {
    printf ("Error, line %d in wrong format!\n\n", line);
}
```

Looks a lot cleaner to me!

Comment: Yeah, but I think it's worth it avoiding nested blocks.

Comment: And why is this an improvement? Do these two even compile into different assembler?

Comment: @Kos it is not a time optimization, you are correct. But still I think it is makes the code look more organized.