# How to handle lag spikes

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I am getting lag spikes in my application, and am wondering how I could find what code is causing the spikes easily

The app is just a third person game (no networking)

Comment: Are the spikes regular? If so, then what are you doing with that interval?

Answer (score 0):

Profile your code, detect the bottlenecks and optimize.

For windows, take a look into this question and answers for tools to profile the code : [What's the best free C++ profiler for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67554/476681)

You can use [gDEBugger](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/gDEBugger/) whether the bottleneck is on the GPU

Comment: I have access to the visual studio profiler, but it does not seem to help with one-frame spikes