# Is there a tool for visualizing cache in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management

When optimizing, or just as an educational tool, it is useful to be able to see exactly where stuff has gone in memory, visualizing allocations/deallocations, etc. I know Valgrind is used in the Linux world. What about in VS?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Team edition comes with profiling tools, VTune is now called VTune Amplify XE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of choices

1. [Glow Code](http://www.glowcode.com/)
2. [Intel VTune Amplify XE](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe)
3. Visual Studio 2012 Team edition comes with profiling tools

None of the above are free

There is also AMD:

1. [AMD CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/CodeAnalyst/archive/Pages/default.aspx) this is free but without all the bells and whistles of Intel's product

Also this is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are)