# Face detection using Viola Jones in openCV

Tags: opencv, time, face-detection, viola-jones

I am now comparing the time performance of Viola-Jones code between the one that is written in pure C code and one that uses openCV function cvHaarDetectObjects().

So far, it seems that the time it takes to detect faces with pure C code is about three times of that of using the openCV function. Even though the pure C code version uses the simplified algorithm.

Can anyone give me a hint on this please?

Comment: Do you use some kind of parallelization on the pure C code version? I think OpenCv uses OpenMP or something similar in order to improve performance, since the Viola-Jones algorithm is highly parallelizable.

Comment: OpenCV uses Intel's TBB to optimize the algorithm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some profiler to compare both implementations speed and see in which part there is the biggest difference. [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) is my favorite one, but of course it's not the only one - [What's the best free C++ profiler for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows-if-there-are)
Probably OpenCV implementation is much faster, because it uses(in most of operations - not only in Viola-Jones algorithm, but in basic operations too) parallelization, processor extensions like MMX, SSE(different versions) and optimizations tricks(which often are quite weird - http://www.beyond3d.com/content/articles/8).