# Debugging - Time consumed in each of the functions

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

**Question:** While debugging in Visual Studio 2012, is there a plugin or a feature which allows me to see the total time spent in each of the functions executed through the program?

**Situation:** There is this code for a game we've written and frames are slow on certain systems(works fine on my lappy, not on school pc which has better config). We need to find which function among the many executed between two consecutive frames is taking maximum amount of time.

NOTE : We're using C++.

Comment: There is no studio features, I suggest using a profiling tool like ANTS

Comment: @asawyer Anything for C++?

Comment: @Cheeku please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows)