# Is there any way to know the total memory consuming by the current program?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-management

**Note:** The program is just an example, main questions are just after this.

Suppose, I have a `C++` program like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>numbers = {4,5,3,2,5,42};
    cout<<"-------------------\n";
    for (auto x : numbers){
        cout<< &x <<endl;
        x+=10;
    }

    cout<<"-------------------\n";
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it!=numbers.end(); it++){
        cout<< &(*it) <<" "<< *it << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
-------------------
0x28fed4
0x28fed4
0x28fed4
0x28fed4
0x28fed4
0x28fed4
-------------------
0x3b21a8 4
0x3b21ac 5
0x3b21b0 3
0x3b21b4 2
0x3b21b8 5
0x3b21bc 42
```

From the memory addresses and increasing values, it is clear that `auto` is using the variable `x` each time which is in a new memory.

Now, I want to know, is there any way to know (built-in function or something like that):

- How much memory the program used from the beginning to end of its execution?
- What is the maximum memory it used?
- How much memory currently it is using?

I am using C++ in *Code::Blocks 13.12* in *Windows 8.1*

Comment: Short answer yes.  In windows you can use task manager and find the task that you have running.  A super hacky way would be to load up all of your memory in a worst case and call `cin`  then you can view the memory consumption.  In linux I believe you can use `ps` command.  As to how you would capture this information in a Dynamic fashion you could try `perf` maybe?

Comment: @Matt I could not get it. I need a little bit broad answer.

Comment: Taking addresses of any local variable is a premature pessimization. It doesn't tell you much. `x` would most likely exist only in registers, had you not taken its address. The address of `&(*it)` is the address of a location within the vector's data. I don't quite understand what else were you expecting - the semantics of `std::vector` are such that data must be contiguous. Once you have the addresses of any two items, you have them all.

Comment: Your code is basically useless, it seems you have introduced it for no purpose whatsoever. It has nothing to do with your question at all.

Comment: @manetsus  I mean like run the program to the point where you've consumed as much memory as you think you'll possibly consume and then have the program call `cin` so it pauses execution.  Then you can use Windows/Linux/OSX to view the amount of memory that your process is consuming.

Comment: @KubaOber: Definitely you are right. My code is just an example. Any other code would work.

Comment: @KubaOber I mention it in latest edit, is it okay now?

Answer (score 5):

Use a memory profiler.

On linux, e.g. use `valgrind --tool=massif`.

Demo:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:            ./test
Massif arguments:   (none)
ms_print arguments: massif.out.26621
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


     B
   40^                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
     |                                                                      :#
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->Mi
     0                                                                   1.397

Number of snapshots: 4
 Detailed snapshots: [2 (peak)]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0              0                0                0             0            0
  1      1,425,892               40               24            16            0
  2      1,464,762               40               24            16            0
60.00% (24B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->60.00% (24B) 0x400B2D: main (new_allocator.h:104)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3      1,464,762                0                0             0            0
```

[image]

Comment: There are memory profiling tools builtin to Visual Sutdio as far as I know

Comment: This is a better solution than task manager haha.  Thanks for this @sehe.

Comment: @sehe unfortunately,  I could not get what is profiling

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(information_science) se [What's the best free profiler for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554/whats-the-best-free-c-profiler-for-windows) e.g.